# Overwriting a char[ ] in C

Tags: c, char

I'm a CS student and I'm trying to figure out pointers in C.  I have:

```
char atest[] = "this is a test";
```

it prints, all is well.

Then I'm trying to do:

```
atest[] = "atest is now changed";
```

and it won't let me.  Why?  Can I never change a char[] without using a function?

Thanks all

Comment: You need `strcpy()` to do what you want: `strcpy(atest, "atest is now changed");` but the 2nd string is larger than the first and the array is not large enough to hold all of it, you invoke **Undefined Behaviour**. Make the array larger than absolutely necessary with `char atest[1000] = "this is a test";` Otherwise, without using a function, you can change each element of the array by itself: `atest[0] = 'a'; atest[1] = 't'; ... atest[19] = 'd'; atest[20] = '\0';`

Answer (score 1):

```
char atest[] = "this is a test";
```

Tells the compiler to allocate a char array of size 15 on stack

```
't', 'h', 'i', 's', ' ', 'i', 's', ' ', 'a', ' ', 't', 'e', 's', 't', '\0'
```

If you look at `atest[3]` you will see `s`.

---

The next operation

```
atest[] = "atest is now changed";
```

Is array assignment which is not supported. Even if it was, the second string is larger than the array size, attempting to access array out of bound will invoke undefined behavior.

---

You may though use [strcpy](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_strcpy.htm)

```
strcpy(atest, "new string");
```

Just make sure it's not bigger than initial array size.

Answer (score 0):

You can not changed char arr by assign operator(=).
You can do this.

`strcpy(atest, "changed");`